# Not understanding how to get cv2.solvepnp object points

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, perspectivecamera

I’m having some confusion in determining the object coordinate points in the cv2.solvePnP() function. Here’s what I’m trying to do. I have a qrcode on an object, and I know the exact width and height of that qrcode. I also have code that will detect that qrcode and send back the bounding box coordinates of the qrcode (4 points of (x,y) values). I now want to determine the 3D rotation and translation matrix of the camera with respect to the qrcode based on this information.

My thought was to use cvs.solvePnP to determine the matrix. So I have my imagePoints as the bounding box returned from the qrcode detection (4 x,y points), I have my camera matrix, and I have my distortion matrix. The big question is, how do I get the object (i.e. world) coordinates??

As one thought, is it that the x and y object points will be the width and height of my qrcode in real life (since I know the exact size of the printed qrcode)? But what would the z be since the camera will be moving up and down different points of the z axis? Or do I just make up a random object coordinate system?

Maybe I’m misunderstanding this function completely? I have the following code so far where right now I’m just making up a random object coordinate system. But with that, I’m not sure how to interpret the results.

```
image_points = np.array([(294, 136),(292, 211),(372, 209),(371, 132)], dtype="double")

# 3D model points.
model_points = np.array([(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0),(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)])

# Camera internals
focal_length = 349.298
camera_matrix = np.array([[focal_length, 0, 356.177],[0, focal_length, 192.877],[0, 0, 1]], dtype = "double")

dist_coeffs = np.array([-0.169513, 0.0218559, 0, 0])

(success, rotation_vector, translation_vector) = cv2.solvePnP(model_points, image_points, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, flags=cv2.SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE)

rotM = cv2.Rodrigues(rotation_vector)[0]
cameraPosition = -np.matrix(rotM).T * np.matrix(translation_vector)
```

My results:

```
Camera Matrix :
 [[ 349.298    0.     356.177]
 [   0.     349.298  192.877]
 [   0.       0.       1.   ]]
Distortion Matrix:
 [-0.169513   0.0218559  0.         0.       ]
Rotation Vector:
 [[-0.10001903]
 [ 1.49954593]
 [ 0.15751248]]
Translation Vector:
 [[-0.06344466]
 [-0.33651584]
 [ 0.49100172]]
rotM: [[ 0.06377104 -0.16581526  0.98409276]
 [ 0.04228612  0.98566325  0.16333966]
 [-0.99706827  0.03119712  0.06986845]]
cam position: [[ 0.50783811]
 [ 0.30585336]
 [ 0.08309628]]
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: depends on where you set your 3D coordinate system for that object. Most people would choose z=0 and either top-left point to (0,0,0) or object center to (0,0,0) but you could choose any other 2D rectplaced in a 3D coordinate system.

Comment: camera movement is not a problem, since you will get the relative object movement compared to an assumed static camera. If for example you choose object center to be the origin, your object is static and your camera moves left, solvePnP will result in object movement to the right. Similarly you will get different results if you choose the origin differently or if the object and camera move, but none of the ways is better or more correct, but some representations might be more intuitiv or more easy to use than others.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for the quick reply!